# Wordpress - Can't get the content of my pages. Receiving an error about post-template.php

Tags: php, wordpress

I am editing my page.php file and trying to show the specific page content on each page. I am able to see the title but for the content I am receiving an error.

This is the error I'm seeing:

> Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\post-template.php on line 310

After searching about it, people says there's something wrong with PHP v. 7.2. I am using PHP v. 7.3. People are also saying they should deactivate any plugins, but I haven't installed anyone.

**Here's the page.php file**

```php
<?php
    /**
    * Template Name: Mallsida
    */
?>  
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main role="main">
    <section class="page-bg" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1><?php single_post_title();?></h1>
    </section>
    <section class="page-content">
        <div class="container">
            <h2><?php single_post_title();?></h2>
            <p><?php the_content()?></p>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the problem is because you are not using the default wordpress loop functions and then calling the_content
See the code below:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main role="main">
    <section class="page-bg" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
        <h1><?php single_post_title();?></h1>
    </section>
    <section class="page-content">
        <div class="container">
            <?php 
            //modified here--------
            if ( have_posts() ) {
                while ( have_posts() ) {
                    the_post(); 

                    the_content();
                }
            }
            //finishing modification
            ?>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

## Another note:

don't use the 



 tag around **the_content** use only block tags like **div, section and others**

Comment: Using that loop though I am fetching all the posts I have. Not the content from the specific page (static content).

Comment: Not necessarily. WordPress by default will only return the current page loop if it is a page for example it will only return the page loop which is the page content.

Comment: Another option is to use code similar to this <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $post->post_content); ?> instead of **the_content ()**

$post->post_content = exchange this for the page content text